# can't using foreach for collection Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, eloquent

I'm creating an edit page of a group-making of an organization. each group consists of a mentor and some mentees.

The problem is i can't iterate using the result because it is a collection of a collection and a user, instead of giving a (directly) collection of user. 
the error is this

`ErrorException in dd3280396f5fc9a234b8faac1b17b55bd5c30ae2.php line 77:
Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$id (View: E:\Documents\Karya\simentor\resources\views\group\edit.blade.php)`

Here's the result of `dd($mentees)`

```
Collection {#260 ▼
  #items: array:2 [▼
    0 => Collection {#286 ▼
      #items: array:1 [▼
        0 => User {#284 ▶}
      ]
    }
    1 => User {#261 ▶}
      ]
    }
```

To get all mentors and mentees who don't have any group yet and to get the mentor and mentees of the to-be-edited group, i did this in `GroupController.php`

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $group = Group::find($id);

    //get mentor and mentee who don't have group yet
    $unassignedMentors = User::whereHas(
                            'roles', function ($q) {
                                $q->where('name', 'mentor');
                            })
                            ->doesntHave('groups')
                            ->get();

    $unassignedMentees = User::whereHas(
                            'roles', function ($q) {
                                $q->where('name', 'mentee');
                            })
                            ->doesntHave('groups')
                            ->get();

    //get mentor and mentee of the to-be-edited group
    $assignedMentor = $group->mentor();
    $assignedMentee = $group->mentee();

    //combine those mentors and mentees into a collection
    $mentors = $unassignedMentors->prepend($assignedMentor);
    $mentees = $unassignedMentees->prepend($assignedMentee);

    return view('group.edit', compact('group', 'mentees', 'mentors', 'assignedMentor', 'assignedMentee'));
}
```

The `mentor()` and `mentee()` method defined in `Group.php` like this

```
public function mentor()
{
    return $this->users()->whereHas(
                    'roles', function($q){
                        $q->where('name', 'mentor');
                    })
                ->first();
}

public function mentee()
{
    return $this->users()->whereHas(
                    'roles', function($q){
                        $q->where('name', 'mentee');
                    })
                ->get();
}
```

Here's the code to display the checkboxes and names in `edit.blade.php`

```
@foreach ($mentees as $mentee) 
   <tr>
     <td><input type="checkbox" name="mentee_id[]" value="{{$mentee->id}}" {{ array_has($assignedMentee, $mentee) ? 'checked' : '' }}></td> --> line 77
     <td>{{ucwords($mentee->profile->name)}}</td>
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Error clearly states that `in dd3280396f5fc9a234b8faac1b17b55bd5c30ae2.php line 77` you try to use `Collection->id` and your object does not have such property. Next time read error message before panicking.

Comment: yeah, i am trying to access the $user->id of a collection of users. but from the 'mentee()', i get a collection of collection of users. could you please suggest an improvement so that i can get a collection of user from the `mentee()` method?